# Unreasonable CPU consumption for server build with nographics

Tags: unity, graphics, performance, profiling

I have built my game in server mode on Mac OS and attached profiler to it. In profiler I can see unreasonable high cpu load.

1. Other scripts take a lot of cpu time. How can this be optimized?
   [image: screenshot]
2. Vsync takes a lot of time otherwise. How can it be since I have disabled VSync, built as server, run with -nographics and even removed cameras and UI?
   [image: screenshot]